# Importing DatetimeOffset Data into Snowflake

Tags: sql-server

When I load DatatimeOffset Data into Snowflake the offset defaults to the Timezone of America/Los_Angeles.

The only question I have besides this is how we maintain the provided UTC offset with our TIMESTAMP_TZ fields?

I have attached an example of the Source Data in PARQUET form along with an example of the SQL script I use to import the data into Snowflake.

Any help would be great!

[SQL Server Source Data Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jcMc.png)

[Snowflake Target Database with the Incorrect Offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjbgM.png)

[PARQUET File Link](https://bizdata365-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/matthew_aylward_bizdata_com_au/EVpiOzMPBSlItuKxrd86rZ4B2I93Oc7T-BgCWatqwQ_FSw?e=CMajkX)

SQL Script:

```
USE DATABASE DEMO_WH;
USE WAREHOUSE DEMO_WH;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "alex_test"."DATETIMEOFFSETTABLETEST";
CREATE TRANSIENT TABLE "alex_test"."DATETIMEOFFSETTABLETEST"("TASKEXECUTIONID" INTEGER NULL ,"LOADDATETIME" TIMESTAMP NULL ,"DATANAME" VARCHAR(50) NULL ,"DATE" TIMESTAMP_TZ NULL ,"DATE_NTZ" TIMESTAMP NULL );
COPY INTO "alex_test"."DATETIMEOFFSETTABLETEST" FROM ( SELECT 3923, CAST('2019-10-13 23:22:14.951' AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)), $1:"DataName"::VARCHAR, $1:"Date"::TIMESTAMP, $1:"Date_NTZ"::TIMESTAMP FROM @~/DGStg/dbo.DatetimeOffsetTableTest.parquet) FILE_FORMAT =(TYPE = 'PARQUET' BINARY_AS_TEXT = FALSE );
```

Comment: Having the same issue, would be really nice to get some exposure on this.

Answer (score 0):

-- In Snowflake you can view your current **TIMEZONE** parameter with this command (Default is America/Los_Angeles):

`show parameters like 'TIMEZONE' in account;`

-- You can view your current **timestamp_type_mapping** parameter with this command (Default is no time zone TIMESTAMP_NTZ)

`show parameters like 'timestamp_type_mapping' in account;`

-- If you want to change parameters for the user/session/account you can do something like this:

`alter account SET TIMEZONE = "UTC";`

-- The copy statement you provided will get you same results you have for SQL Server if your timezone is set to UTC:

`COPY INTO DATETIMEOFFSETTABLETEST FROM ( SELECT 3923, CAST('2019-10-13 23:22:14.951' AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)), $1:DataName::VARCHAR, $1:Date::TIMESTAMP, $1:Date_NTZ::TIMESTAMP FROM @my_aws_stage/stack) FILE_FORMAT =(TYPE = 'PARQUET' BINARY_AS_TEXT = FALSE );`

-- If for some reason you didn't want to change the timezone you can insert as UTC using the **convert_timezone** function:

`COPY INTO DATETIMEOFFSETTABLETEST FROM ( SELECT 3923, CAST(convert_timezone('UTC','2019-10-13 23:22:14.951') AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)), $1:DataName::VARCHAR, convert_timezone('UTC','UTC',$1:Date)::TIMESTAMP, convert_timezone('UTC','UTC',$1:Date_NTZ)::TIMESTAMP FROM @my_aws_stage/stack) FILE_FORMAT =(TYPE = 'PARQUET' BINARY_AS_TEXT = FALSE );`

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/date-time-examples.html
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html#convert-timezone